# Does the of lenght of checksum help correct error?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, checksum

I am doing a small research on bit stuffing, however i am unsuccessful in finding out how does the checksum play a role in bit stuffing. the unanswered question i have are does the length of a checksum help correct errors  if yes what type of errors a long checksum correct and also the type of error a short checksum correct compare both?

Answer (score 0):

Checksums don't correct errors at all, whether long or short. They *detect* them.

Techniques like Reed-Solomon encoding as used in CDs can be used for error correction by providing redundant information.

Keep researching.